# Cloud 9 IDE bash: rebar: command not found

Tags: installation, cloud9-ide, rebar

Locally I can install rebar, get-deps, and compile. On C9 I do the exact same steps and I get bash: rebar: command not found when doing rebar get-deps.

My terminal is running -bash. Not sure what else I can do.

I tried rebar/rebar and ./rebar

Using this rebar version: https://github.com/rebar/rebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install rebar with `sudo apt-get install rebar` then run `rebar`.

Answer (score 0):

install rebar manually

```
git clone https://github.com/basho/rebar.git
cd rebar && make
```

it will generate a exec file: `rebar`.  You can copy it to your project directory or to `/usr/local/bin`